# How to get "property" and "appliances" data from the json in python?

Tags: python, screen-scraping

How can I find the "property" and "appliances" key's data in Python?

```
{
     "apiCache": "{\"VariantQuery{\\\"zpid\\\":2070457223,\\\"altId\\\":null}\":{\"property\":{\"zpid\":2070457223,\"streetAddress\":\"0 E 1990th Rd\",\"zipcode\":\"74759\",\"city\":\"Soper\",\"state\":\"OK\",\"APPS_IOS_GOOGLE_TRANSITION\":\"ON_SIGNED_URLS\",\"SXP_PHOTO_CAROUSEL\":\"CONTROL\",\"ADT_COOKIE_CONSENT\":\"ONETRUST\",\"SEOTEST__CUSTOM_REGION_FAQ_FOR_SALE_V1\":\"CONTROL\",\"ADS_FiOSAd\":\"ON\",\"HDP_PSL_PHOTOS\":\"ON\",\"HDP_ZO_NFS_UPSELL_ONSITE_MESSAGING\":\"CONTROL\",\"AndroidWowMapDotsV0\":\"ON_WOW_DOTS_WITH_HRS\",\"REV_Replace_PALS_CC_Form_With_CSI_Functionality\":\"CONTROL\",\"SRP_DESKTOP_ADS_VARIANTS\":\"VARIANT_B\",\"TR_ORGANIC_HIGHLIGHTS\":\"CONTROL\",\"VL_BDP_NYDOS\":\"ON\",\"HDP_FULL_SSR_NFS\":\"ON\",\"FOUNDATION_COLORS_TYPOGRAPHY\":\"CONTROL\",\"ADS_EPA_SHOW_OTHER_LEADS\":\"ON\",\"HDP_VT_HIGHER\":\"ON\",\"SEO__SXP_REMOVE_ANCHOR_TEXT\":\"CONTROL\",\"SEOTEST__RE_SRPTitleTags_CityStateHomesForRent\":\"CONTROL\",\"SavedSearchInstantSMS\":\"CONTROL\",\"REALTIME_PERS_SORT_PRE\":\"REALTIME_RECS\",\"NOTIFICATION_SERVICE\":\"CACHED\",\"VELOCITY_TimeIsMoney\":\"CONTROL\",\"MOBILE_ZO_VALUEPROP\":\"VALUEPROP_ON\",\"ACT_AutocompleteHW\":\"CONTROL\",\"ARCS_REGION_PHONE\":\"ON\",\"IOS_HDP_TOP_ACTIONS\":\"CONTROL_OFF\",\"ACQ_TOP_DISMISSLOGIC_Relaunch_2wksVS24hrs\":\"Variant_Relaunch_24hrs\",\"Traffic_Mobile_Menu_Button\":\"APP_STYLE\",\"ARCS_LISTEDBY\":\"CONTROL\",\"IOS_CURRENT_LOCATION\":\"CONTROL_ON\",\"HDP_NO_CARDS\":\"ON\",\"RR_TourSchedulingOnOffSwitch\":\"CONTROL\",\"SELLiveViewsUI\":\"CONTROL\",\"PERS_HOME_INSIGHTS_POSITION\":\"INSIGHTS_MID\",\"IOS_SHARE_SHEET\":\"ON_2\",\"SPT_PSL_PRICE_HISTORY\":\"ON\",\"KeystoneEventHDP\":\"SEND_EVENT\",\"HDP_HarrietZestimate\":\"TOOLS_MODULE\",\"IOS_HOMERECOMMENDATIONS_V1\":\"ON\",\"IOS_HOMERECOMMENDATIONS_V2\":\"CONTROL_OFF\",\"NOTIFICATION_ADMIN_PAGE_ONLY\":\"ADMIN_PAGE_ONLY\",\"SXP_ACT_REMOVE_SEARCHBOX_GLEAM\":\"NO_GLEAM\",\"appliances\":[\"Cooktop\",\"Electric Water Heater\",\"Microwave\",\"Oven\",\"Refrigerator\",\"Electric Range\"],\"ARCS_TOUR_MESSAGE\":\"CONTROL\",\"ARCS_TOUR_TIME\":\"TIME_SHOWN\",\"ARCS_TOUR_REWRITE\":\"ON\",\"ARCS_WOW_LISTING_AGENT_ATTRIBUTION\":\"ON\",\"ARCS_CONTACTABLE_LISTING_AGENT\":\"CONTROL\",\"ARCS_DESKTOP_PHONE\":\"CONTROL\",\"contactFormRenderData\":null}}",
     "zpid": 2070457223
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library in python to read a json string into a dictionary, which you can then use to access the keys you want, like so:

```
import json
data_json = '{ "apiCache": "{"VariantQuery{\"zpid\":2070457223,\"altId\":null}":{"property":{"zpid":2070457223,"streetAddress":"0 E 1990th Rd","zipcode":"74759","city":"Soper","state":"OK","APPS_IOS_GOOGLE_TRANSITION":"ON_SIGNED_URLS","SXP_PHOTO_CAROUSEL":"CONTROL","ADT_COOKIE_CONSENT":"ONETRUST","SEOTEST__CUSTOM_REGION_FAQ_FOR_SALE_V1":"CONTROL","ADS_FiOSAd":"ON","HDP_PSL_PHOTOS":"ON","HDP_ZO_NFS_UPSELL_ONSITE_MESSAGING":"CONTROL","AndroidWowMapDotsV0":"ON_WOW_DOTS_WITH_HRS","REV_Replace_PALS_CC_Form_With_CSI_Functionality":"CONTROL","SRP_DESKTOP_ADS_VARIANTS":"VARIANT_B","TR_ORGANIC_HIGHLIGHTS":"CONTROL","VL_BDP_NYDOS":"ON","HDP_FULL_SSR_NFS":"ON","FOUNDATION_COLORS_TYPOGRAPHY":"CONTROL","ADS_EPA_SHOW_OTHER_LEADS":"ON","HDP_VT_HIGHER":"ON","SEO__SXP_REMOVE_ANCHOR_TEXT":"CONTROL","SEOTEST__RE_SRPTitleTags_CityStateHomesForRent":"CONTROL","SavedSearchInstantSMS":"CONTROL","REALTIME_PERS_SORT_PRE":"REALTIME_RECS","NOTIFICATION_SERVICE":"CACHED","VELOCITY_TimeIsMoney":"CONTROL","MOBILE_ZO_VALUEPROP":"VALUEPROP_ON","ACT_AutocompleteHW":"CONTROL","ARCS_REGION_PHONE":"ON","IOS_HDP_TOP_ACTIONS":"CONTROL_OFF","ACQ_TOP_DISMISSLOGIC_Relaunch_2wksVS24hrs":"Variant_Relaunch_24hrs","Traffic_Mobile_Menu_Button":"APP_STYLE","ARCS_LISTEDBY":"CONTROL","IOS_CURRENT_LOCATION":"CONTROL_ON","HDP_NO_CARDS":"ON","RR_TourSchedulingOnOffSwitch":"CONTROL","SELLiveViewsUI":"CONTROL","PERS_HOME_INSIGHTS_POSITION":"INSIGHTS_MID","IOS_SHARE_SHEET":"ON_2","SPT_PSL_PRICE_HISTORY":"ON","KeystoneEventHDP":"SEND_EVENT","HDP_HarrietZestimate":"TOOLS_MODULE","IOS_HOMERECOMMENDATIONS_V1":"ON","IOS_HOMERECOMMENDATIONS_V2":"CONTROL_OFF","NOTIFICATION_ADMIN_PAGE_ONLY":"ADMIN_PAGE_ONLY","SXP_ACT_REMOVE_SEARCHBOX_GLEAM":"NO_GLEAM","appliances":["Cooktop","Electric Water Heater","Microwave","Oven","Refrigerator","Electric Range"],"ARCS_TOUR_MESSAGE":"CONTROL","ARCS_TOUR_TIME":"TIME_SHOWN","ARCS_TOUR_REWRITE":"ON","ARCS_WOW_LISTING_AGENT_ATTRIBUTION":"ON","ARCS_CONTACTABLE_LISTING_AGENT":"CONTROL","ARCS_DESKTOP_PHONE":"CONTROL","contactFormRenderData":null}}", "zpid": 2070457223 }'
data_dict = json.loads(data_json)
appliances = data_dict['property']['appliances']
print(appliances)
```

Note: this code doesn't quite run as the json listed in the question is invalid.